# Passing parameter in XSL

Tags: xml, variables, xslt, parameters

I'm an XSL beginner struggling with a parameter problem.

My XML looks likes this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <Enterprise CompanyName="Some Name">
   <HeaderData FileName="File21.xml" SequenceNumber="00021"/>
   <DetailData CusomterID="2">
      <Location LocationID="Some Location1" Name="SomeName">
         <Address StreetName="Name of the street"/>
         <Contact Name="" FunctionDescription=""/>
      </Location>
      <Location LocationID="Some Location2" Name="SomeName">
         <Address StreetName="Name of the street"/>
         <Contact Name="" FunctionDescription=""/>
      </Location>
   </DetailData>
   <FooterData NumOfTags="7"/>
</Enterprise>
```

In the stylesheet I want to add the Sequencenumber from the HeaderData to each Location element in the DetailData.
I tried xsl:param, xsl:variable in the root node, outside the rootnode, nothing works for me.

Hope somenone can help. Thanks.

Comment: So why do you think you need to use an `xsl:param`eter? From each `Location` element you can simply select the `parent::DetailData/preceding-sibling::HeaderData/@SequenceNumber`.

Comment: Post the stylesheet you have so far.

Comment: Thanks Martin!! As I said, XSL beginner ;-) Your solution works perfectly!